# How to specify maven properties in a aggregator POM?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project structure like below.In aggregator POM project1 and project 2 are defined as modules.Now if i want to add a maven property that can be accessed in all the projects how can i do it?.
What is the best project structure in this case.?

If i define property like `<temp.dir>data</temp.dir>` in the aggregator POM then it is not available in project1 pom.xml and project2 POM.xml.I have to duplicate the same property in both the POM's.

```
project
- project1
- - pom.xml  ---- has parent POM as project A
- project2
- - pom.xml  --- has parent POM as project B
- pom.xml (Aggregator POM)
```

UPDATE:To clarify more project1 pom and project 2 has different parent POM's.So aggregator POM cannot be set as parent.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to set the aggregator pom as the parent of `project1` and `project2`.
eg. in `project1` and `project2` poms add:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.agr</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-aggregator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

EDIT:

I understand that project1 and project2 have different parent poms.

The only solution i know about to achieve what You want is to store the properties in parent pom.

I can think only of one solution, to make an inheritance chain:

Project2Parent:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project1Parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Project2Parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
```

Aggregator:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project2Parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Aggregator</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
```

Project1

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Aggregator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>project1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
```

Project2

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Aggregator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>project2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
```

Comment: I cannot set the aggregator POM as parent as project1 and project2 have different parent POM's.

Comment: I edited the post with an example that can help to achieve what You want.., that's only if You can modify one of the ParentPoms in eg. the Project2Parent pom

Comment: Does that work? I mean now they still have the same parent, (or better parents) what means that  Parent2 overwrites Parent1

Comment: Parent2 does not override parent1 only inherits from it, the project1 and project2 will have all the properties from Parent1, Parent2 and Aggregator available.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is describing a real use case in large companies that have required parent POMs for different project types: library or service.  Any real project in that company may include some jar modules (library parent) and a REST service or web UI (service parent).

All the Maven inheritance happens from the external parent POMs. But it would be real nice if developers could set a few properties in the aggregator POM.

Apparently, however, this is not possible with Maven.

Answer (score -2):

Here is aggregator's pom:

```xml
<groupId>y</groupId>
<artifactId>y</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>y1</module>
    <module>y2</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <x>1</x>
</properties>
```

This is `y1` effective pom (generated by Eclipse):

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>y</groupId>
    <artifactId>y</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>y1</groupId>
  <artifactId>y1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <properties>
    <x>1</x>
  </properties>
```

As you can see property `x` declared in parent is inherited by child.

Comment: Y1 has another parent POM so the aggregator POM cannot be set as parent.